# Evaluating the product of a matrix sequence

Tags: matrix, products

I want to compute
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n A_i = A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n
$$
where every $A_i$ is a square matrix. When I execute

```
a[i_] := {{1, i}, {0, 1}};
Product[a[i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

Mathematica gives the element-wise product, which is not what I need. The desired result can be obtained by

```
Fold[Dot, IdentityMatrix[2], Table[a[i], {i, 1, 10}]]
```

but I'm curious if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 7):

```
Dot @@ (a /@ Range@10)

 (* {{1, 55}, {0, 1}} *)
```

Also

```
Dot @@ Array[a, 10]
```

Comment: Didn't know that `Dot` accepts more than 2 arguments